# Referencing while a mut reference exists in scope

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have this code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = "My string".to_string();
    let ref1 = &mut s;
    // let ref2 = &s; //Doesn't compile
    let ref3 = &*ref1; //*ref1 is s. So &*ref1 is &s => compiles
}
```

`let ref2 = &s;` does not compile because there is already a mut reference in the scope. However, `let ref3 = &*ref1` does compile.

As far as my understanding goes, `*ref1` should return the `s`. So `&*ref1` should be `&s` and it compiles for some reason.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Rusts borrowing works as follows:
Either you have **one mutable** reference or **n immutable** references.

- `let ref1 = &mut s;` creates a mutable reference to s.
- `let ref2 = &s;` tries to create an immutable reference to s.
  This is obviously not possible. We already have a mutable reference
  to s.

`let ref3 = &*ref1;` creates an immutable reference to `*ref1`

If you would try to assgn to `ref1` afterwords it would not work:

`*ref1 = "Other string".to_string();`

results in:

`error: cannot assign to '*ref1' because it is borrowed [E0506]`

Keep in mind, that borrows are scoped. See following example: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1ce659b5fc2d5c1dc74e3a0d61ee9db0&version=stable&backtrace=0)

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = "My string".to_string();
    {
        let ref1 = &mut s;
        //println!("{}", s); //Does not compile. s is borrowed as mutable
        {
            let ref3 = &(*ref1); //*ref1 is now borrowed as immutable.
            println!("{}", ref1); //We can read it
            //*ref1 = "Other string".to_string();//but not assign to it
            println!("{}", ref3);
        }
        //ref3 is now out of scope and so is the immutable borrow
        *ref1 = "Other string".to_string();//We can now assign to *ref1
        println!("{}", ref1);
    }
    //Now that the mutable borrow from ref1 is out of scope, we can read s again
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

Comment: You said "let ref3 = &*ref1; creates an immutable reference to *ref1"
But `*ref1` is `s` right? which means it is an immutable reference to `s`. This is where I am getting confused. As you said, one mut or n immutable. 
In my code example, there is one mut and 1 immutable reference to s. But it compiles.

Comment: But as soon as you borrow immutable from the mutable reference, it becomes immutable for the time of the borrow. So basically there are only immutable references left.
This is what happens in the example in line 8 and 9.

Comment: @EmperorAiman I believe the key term here will be "reborrowing". See if a search on SO finds anything useful with that term?

Comment: Rust doesn't try to track references to where they come from; while it would be easy in this case, it's impossible in others; so the only context it keeps (at compile time) for a reference is its lifetime.  As @Shepmaster says, after `let ref3 = &*ref1`, you've reborrowed `s` via `ref1`.  `ref1` is no longer accessible while the sub-borrow is in scope (just like `s` is no longer directly accessible while `ref1` is in scope).

Comment: I understand now. Thanks guys. Reborrowing is the thing I was looking for. It's a shame it is not there in the beginner rust book :/